# Error while running Spotify, libva error; init failed

Tags: init, spotify

I'm getting this error while running Spotify:

```
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you running a supported Ubuntu release? How did you install `spotify`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to install [corresponding](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=iHD_drv_video.so) Intel driver package by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intel-media-driver
```

then reboot and retry.