# Snap problem with spotify

Tags: software-installation, snap, spotify

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 from a fresh iso, and when I installed Spotify from the snap hub I got this error message.

[image: that error]

Someone on IRC had redirected me to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1384489/), but it gives me this error when trying to install the driver.

[image: this error]

I was able to add the universe repository, but it seems like I can't find the driver I need.

Comment: 1. Please copy/paste text output to your Question above. Linking to images of text is frowned upon here. 2. Your output clearly shows that your key error is not related to adding `universe`. Your key error is related to adding spotify deb repository...which seems strange since your question is about using the spotify snap package instead spotify deb package(s).

Comment: Well, I ran `sudo add-apt-repository universe ` and `sudo apt update` and now it gives me this output  when trying to install the driver `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package intel-media-driver`

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. `rmadison` and http://packages.ubuntu.com disagree on whether this package is in the repos or not. Sorry for the wrong steer (now deleted). As usual, @karel is on the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out i didnt have to install it , i rebooted my computer and spotify now works. I also downloaded the 525 drivers proprietary tested i dont know if thats why, or maybe i just needed to add universe repository and reboot